# adding WYSIWYG edito to form builder

Tags: javascript, meteor, formbuilder, froala

i'm using this form builder with meteor , and i need to be able to make the textArea a WYSIWYG , but the problem is that the libary tracks the elements , and as you know a rich edito is a div not a TextArea .
[FormBuilder](http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

can you not appen a new div under the textarea(hide the textarea first) and transform to a WYSIWYG and put the content from the WYSIWYG to the FormBuilder Textarea on change?